# Openlayers setState on Select event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, setstate

I am trying to trigger a React setState when a feature is clicked. I try to edit the selectedFeature and show it's properties on the screen. But I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" Error message every time i try to execute the click method.

```
componentDidMount() {
    ...

    function featureSelected(event) {
      console.log(event.selected[0].getProperties());
      this.setState({ selectedFeature: event.selected[0].getProperties() });
    }

    var changeInteraction = function() {
      var select = new Select({});
      select.on("select", event => featureSelected(event));
      map.addInteraction(select);
    };

    ...
}
```

This is the line that throws the error:

```
 this.setState({ selectedFeature: event.selected[0].getProperties() });
```

This is my state property:

```
class MyMap extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedFeature: null
  };
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is undefined

Use fat arrow function instead of the function keyword.
You add a new scope when you add a `function`. `this` becomes the `this`
 of the function and not of the class anymore.

A fat arrow function passes the scope of `this` down and will allow you to call class methods like setState.

```
componentDidMount() {
    ...

    const featureSelected = (event) => {
      console.log(event.selected[0].getProperties());
      this.setState({ selectedFeature: event.selected[0].getProperties() });
    }

    var changeInteraction = () => {
      var select = new Select({});
      select.on("select", event => featureSelected(event));
      map.addInteraction(select);
    };

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer! This fixed my problem.

Comment: @user3566338 no problem, hope this explanation of `this` was helpful to you. It's extremely important to understand in JS

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a misconception of `this`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Basically this refers to the closest function parent. In your case this refers to `featureSelected`.
Try creating a reference to the `this` that you need, by storing it into a variable.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    ...
    const myClass=this; //Reference to the above class
    function featureSelected(event) {
      console.log(event.selected[0].getProperties());
      //Use that reference instead of this
      myClass.setState({ selectedFeature: event.selected[0].getProperties() });
    }

    var changeInteraction = function() {
      var select = new Select({});
      select.on("select", event => featureSelected(event));
      map.addInteraction(select);
    };

    ...
}
```